# Running underground wire to a shed

Tags: wiring

I want to run an underground electric cable to a shed which is 200 feet from the house.

I was wondering what the pros and cons were of using an existing overhead line and putting in conduit.

Also what size of wire would be needed as I have a welder in the shed.

Comment: There's already an overhead line feeding the shed, or you want to tap the overhead line feeding your house?

Comment: What is the current rating of the welder?

Comment: The answer to questions like this is almost always, "find your local permitting authority, and ask somebody there".

Answer (score 2):

You CANNOT move the overhead line to underground. Everything from the enclosures, attachments, and the cable itself are different. Basically you'd have to remove the overhead line and associated parts and re-do the run with conduit (or direct bury). Where or not you can use the existing panels and such would need to be determined on site.

In my strong opinion this is not something for a casual DIYer. This is only something for a someone with a good bit of experience in this type of work.

With only knowing you will be running a welder it is impossible to accurately say what wire to use. Personally, with a home shop you'd almost certainly be fine with a 90-100A feeder. You can use 100A MHF cable (mobile home feeder) which is readily available anywhere. IMO anything smaller isn't worth it in the long run. 
One thing, due to the length of the run, you may want to drop the feeder breaker to 70A to curb voltage drop. Again, this all depends on what will be used at the same time.

Comment: Can I suggest dropping the use of ALL CAPS for *emphasis*?  It comes across as YELLING.  Also could you elaborate on your definition of "casual DIYr" or better, detail the challenges involved in this particular project.

Comment: You can suggest all you like. I will NOT change my writing style. I did NOT write in "ALL CAPS", simply a word or two here and there. I think it's pretty obvious that this is done for emphasis and to make words stand out.